Trying to center my div in a div using typescript
I am trying to center my pixel grid in my div using typescript, but I am confused as to why my pixel is not being centered.
I tried nesting my pixel with a container and added the correct CSS to center it, but it's not being centered.
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className ="text-2xl font-bold mb-4 text-center p-4">myPixel</h1>
      <div className ="w-full h-96 p-4 m-0 rounded-lg border border-black bg-blue-500 flex justify-center items-center">
       <div className="flex justify-center items-center h-screen w-full"> 
        <div className="pixel-one"></div>
        </div>
        </div>

    </div>
  );
}


What CSS Library are you using? Any answers will need to be specific to that.

Are you using tailwindcss, unocss or so?
